# XML serialization of a list with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a list inside another list (a product with variants). I would like the parent list to have attributes set on it (just an `id` and a `name`).

**Desired Output**

```xml
<embellishments>
    <type id="1" name="bar bar foo">
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>foo bar</name>
            <cost>10</cost>
        </row>      
    </type> 
</embellishments>
```

---

**Current Code**

```cs
[XmlRoot( ElementName = "embellishments", IsNullable = false )]
public class EmbellishmentGroup
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="type")]
    [XmlArrayItem("row", Type=typeof(Product))]
    public List<Product> List { get; set; }

    public EmbellishmentGroup() {
        List = new List<Product>();
        List.Add( new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "foo bar", Cost = 10m } );
    }
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlElement( "id" )]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "name" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "cost" )]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Current Output**

```xml
<embellishments>
    <type>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>foo bar</name>
            <cost>10</cost>
        </row>
    </type>
</embellishments>
```

---

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make another class which represents the `type` element.  Then you can add properties to it for the attributes, like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "embellishments", IsNullable = false)]
public class EmbellishmentGroup
{
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public MyType Type { get; set; }

    public EmbellishmentGroup() 
    {
        Type = new MyType();
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("row")]
    public List<Product> List { get; set; }

    public MyType()
    {
        Id = 1;
        Name = "bar bar foo";
        List = new List<Product>();
        Product p = new Product();
        p.Id = 1;
        p.Name = "foo bar";
        p.Cost = 10m;
        List.Add(p);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlElement( "id" )]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "name" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "cost" )]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```