# Is there any way to deserialize xml to object with specified keyword?

Tags: c#, xml

As you can see in blow code I want to deserialize custom xml to object, and I don't know how many code attribute there, so I want to filter all attribute that contains the "code", and map it with List property. Is there any way to implement this feature?

```
<Root>
     <FirstElement FirstCode="1" SecondCode="2" ThirdCode="3" Id="1" Name="Element" />
</Root>

public class MappedClass
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
   public string Name {get;set;}

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [?]
   public List<Code> Codes {get;set;}

}

public Class Code
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811991/xml-serialization-of-a-list-with-attributes

Comment: No its not same question, I want to filter the attribute by specific keyword and map them with List. The number of attributes is not fixed and can change in any request.

Comment: Without adding into list you will not be able to map.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can. Use UnknownAttribute event to place unknown attribute to Codes collection:

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MappedClass));
        serializer.UnknownAttribute += 
            (s, e) =>
            {
                (e.ObjectBeingDeserialized as MappedClass).Codes.Add(new Code { Name = e.Attr.Name, Value = e.Attr.Value });                                        
            };
```